# responsive design with bootstrap in joomla 2.5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, responsive-design

I'm just beginner to bootstrap. I wanted to apply bootstrap css to the menu in joomla 2.5. But this menu is having the css from it's default template i.e. beez5, so the bootstrap css is not working.

The menu is in `ul` tag and no-other divs in `modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php`. There I set `class="span3"` but is taking its style from `class="menu"`. I removed the `class="menu"` but also not taking from the bootstrap.css.

**Question:**

Should I remove the path `beez5.css` from index.php or should I wrap that `ul` tag with a `<div class="container">` in  `modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php` too?

---

I'd like to complete this task without responsive design templates i.e. just using its default template beez5 and using bootstrap.css.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the joostrap template. They really made a good job to implement bootstrap in a joomla template. 
But the most recent version 2.0.0 does still have some lack of features. Currently I would suggest to use the older 1.3.x of Joostrap version which is still available and works fine with Joomla 2.5 and 3.1.x.